# Knockout-sortable nested items can't be dragged into childless element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-sortable

I'm using [knockout-sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) and my goal is [nestedSortable](http://ilikenwf.github.io/example.html) behaviour. I have a working light-weight fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fdf0664t/3/) I've made, and everything is ok except one thing: I can't move children to element who doesnt have it initially.

Child elements prints there:

```
<div data-bind="if: children().length > 0">
    <ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'tpl', data: $data.children }"></ul>            
</div>
```

Even if check removed there's still no room to place child elements.
Is there somewhere good solution for nested sortable for knockout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to give it some height. I took out the `if`, put a class on the ul

```
<div>
  <ul class="sort-drop" data-bind="sortable: { template: 'tpl', data: $data.children }"></ul>
</div>
```

and styled it red so you can see it

```
.sort-drop:empty {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 5px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdf0664t/5/).